# Reprojecting Points, Shapes and Rasters using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile

I have a project file that had originally started out with no care to the actual coordinates (we were just using an aerial and displaying the shapes and points on said aerial). Now, I am trying to convert my old coworkers issues, and one was actually using a geographic coordinate system. I have control points to be able to properly scale each layer down and place it in the proper location coordinate-wise, but is there any way of doing this with QGIS? Or should I just get all of the maps redrawn with the correct coordinates in a new file?

An example would be point A - which is currently as 345, -1329 when it should be at -104.671892198, 38.3189727989 (and the transformation should be the exact same for other points, shapes and raster file).

Comment: What do you mean by 'convert my old coworkers issues'?  What data do you have in your QGIS project? Is it all raster? or are there vectors as well? What are the individual formats? This information is needed, before we can guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qgis has some useful plugins like `Affine Transformations` and `Vector Bender` to georeference vector data. It might be necessary to have more than one reference point if the axis system is rotated against true North.

Just try them out, and come back if you still have questions.

The built-in Georeferencer is designed for raster data, if you need that too.